# Freshbooks API - Global Project ID

Tags: freshbooks-api

I'm integrating Freshbooks with an application at my company and am accessing the Freshbooks API.  We have a few developers that work at our company.  I'm finding that even if several developers are all assigned to the same Project on Freshbooks, when accessing said project via the API on a per user basis, each user has a different Project ID for that one Project.

My question is:  Is there a "common project ID" that all Users who are assigned to that project can access via the API?  The only consistent point of reference seems to be the Freshbooks Project Name -- which is fine except when the Project Name changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I discovered, the reason there is no global project ID across my developers' accounts is because they are all registered as Contractors on Freshbooks and not Staff Members.  Freshbooks makes a distinction here.  Contractors have fully separate accounts, whereas Staff Members can be queried in the API THROUGH the account under which they are staffed -- allowing you to use the same Project ID amongst all Staff Members.